# Android Eclipse ADT Code Errors when starting new Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When I start a new Android project in the Eclipse/ADT bundle, I get 2 errors in the code..
  The 2 warning messages are as follows:

```
   The import android.app.ActionBar is never used
   The import android.os.Build is never used
```

Both of them are in `MainActivity.java`

This is very odd because it happens as soon as I create a new project!
Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: MainActivity.java complete file can you paste. Mostly you might have missed appcompact

Comment: The mainactivity.java file in question is simply the brand new file created when you create a new android project from within the eclipse/adt bundle. So nothing out of the ordinary. That's why it's odd. I couldn't have missed anything because I haven't done anything to it, its a brand new android project. But when and where would these imported things in question typically be used? Maybe that will solve the mystery..

Answer (score 1):

These are not errors, but warnings. Chances are that these classes (`ActionBar` and `Build`) are introduced by the "New Project" wizard which generates code from a generic template. These classes may be useful when you proceed with your project. In case you do not need them, simply remove the `import` statements.

Comment: Well I chose to start a new ANDROID PROJECT, so its not just a generic project template.. I just dont understand why it would put these lines in there if they only return warnings and arent needed. Not only this, but in the past i never had this issue.. Could it be due to something else? perhaps the installations of sdk and adt not matching or something like that? Id like to actually solve it to where it creates a warning-free android project from the start like it used to.. Any ideas?

Comment: The `Activity` created for you from the "New Android Application" wizard is created from a template which contains the generic code segments. If you feel this is a bug, please read and [Report Bugs](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html)

Comment: Exactly. ADT created the new Android project from its new project template with those imports, so I would assume they are necessary. But yet I'm getting those warnings, and I dont understand why they would include them in a new android project template if they were not needed. I don't think its really a bug, so I'm not going to report it. But I do think there's a reason they include them, and a way it can be fixed other than simply removing them. In particular the osbuild import. It sounds very important. Can anybody explain where and when these two imports in question would typically be used?

Comment: You should look at their API documentation. For example, [`ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) is an important UI design pattern that can be found in most of the newer applications. `ActionBar` was introduced in API 11. [`Build`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) is used, among other things, to figure out at runtime the version of the OS. This may be required in case you want to support certain features not available in older versions and also want to stay backwards compatible by filtering out these features on older devices.

Comment: Exactly! Both of them are typical imports, especially considering I'm running all the most updated sdk, build tools, adt, etc. And also set my app to the newest apis when I created the new android project. So there shouldn't be either of these messages popping up, am I right? That's why it seems odd to me! There's gotta be some kind of weird reason why its doing this, right off the bat in a new android project like this. I just can't understand why it would be doing this.